# Pointer to function (list)

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I have to write this program but **I can't do any changes in function main**,
this program works when Node* head is declared as a global Variable (functions does not contain "Node* head" in parameters).
this program compiles successfully, but then is segmentation fault (I know why, Head was not changed and it's still 0, but I don't know how to fix that). Any ideas ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
  int val;
  Node* next;
};
void addBeg(Node* head,int val)
{
  Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  temp->val=val;
  temp->next=head;
  head=temp;
}
int main()
{
  Node* head=0;
  addBeg(head,1);
  cout << head->val << endl; //checking if head was changed correctly 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the head pointer by *reference* if you're going to modify it. Anything else will require modification of `main()`, which is apparently off-limits:

Change this:

```
void addBeg(Node* head, int val)
```

To this:

```
void addBeg(Node*& head, int val) // NOTE: see reference &
```

[See it live here](http://ideone.com/B2QK0S)

That said, you should be using `new`, not `malloc`, and ideally using a standard container like `std::vector<>`, `std::list<>`, `std::deque<>` rather than this, but that is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change pointer inside function send "pointer to pointer", e.g.:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
  int val;
  Node* next;
};
void addBeg(Node** head,int val)    // Node** instead of Node*
{
  Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  temp->val=val;
  temp->next=*head;
  *head=temp;                  // *head  instead of head
}
int main()
{
  Node* head=0;
  addBeg(&head,1);   // &head instead of head
  cout << head->val << endl; //checking if head was changed correctly 
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Or just use reference parameter for pointer:

```cpp
void addBeg(Node* &head,int val)
{
  Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  temp->val=val;
  temp->next=head;
  head=temp;
}
```

Comment: „I can't do any changes in function main” means you cannot write something like addBeg(&head,1); instead of  addBeg(head,1);

Comment: Use reference parameter - change header of `void addBeg(Node* head,int val)` to `void addBeg(Node* &head,int val)`  (and not change body)